# understanding basis

Tags: linear-algebra, definition

Let $L^2(\mathbb R)$ is an infinite-dimensional complex vector space. Let $A= \{f_n: n\in \mathbb N\}$ be  basis in $L^2(\mathbb R).$

> Does there exists
>   $f \in L^2(\mathbb R)$  such that  $f$ cannot be written as finite linear combiation of $f_i\in A$?  In other other words, there exist $f\in L^2$ and there dose not exist any $m\in \mathbb N$ such that $f=\sum_i^m \alpha_i f_i \ (\alpha \in \mathbb C, f_i \in A)$?

Comment: By definition you only know that the set of functions $\sum_{i=1}^m \alpha_i f_i$ is a dense subset of $L^2(\mathbb{R})$.

Comment: In fact if $f_n$ is an orthonormal basis then $g=\sum_{i=1}^\infty (1/n) f_i$ is an element in $L^2(\mathbb{R})$ because $\|g\|_2\leq \sum_{i=1}^\infty 1/{n^2}<\infty$

Comment: and you can use graham schmidt algorithm to convert $f_n$ to an orthonormal basis..